# Custom parameters in media URL query string - Sitecore render method/pipeline

Tags: media-library, pipelines, renderfield

I am using Sitecore's render method to construct the query strings for image assets, but I have a small challenge parsing custom parameters into the rendered query string in the HTML.

It seems that the render pipeline has some logic to interpret certain parameters and adds them to the query string, but anything else it adds as an attribute on the `img` tag (example below).

if you add a parameter such as "h" for height:

```
@imageField.Render(parameters: "h=200")
```

output html:

```
<div class="image ">
  <img src="/~/media/cvi-2-color-icons/icon-faq-384x140.png?h=200" alt="" height="200">
</div>
```

However, if I write something like "optimize":

```
@imageField.Render(parameters: "optimize=200")
```

output html:

```
<div class="image ">
  <img src="/~/media/cvi-2-color-icons/icon-faq-384x140.png" alt="" optimize="200">
</div>
```

Is there a good way to override this behavior or hook into the pipeline and allow additional parameter strings?

Comment: Is .Render an extension method or are you using another framework/mapper?

Comment: An extension method. It will do down and call the renderField pipeline at some point.

But I am just looking for at method to parse additional parameters and have them appended to the query string through the pipeline, like if I used:
`@Html.Sitecore().Field("Image", item.InnerItem, new { h="120", format="jpg"})`
(Where "format" isn't recognised as a parameter, but is only set as an attribute)